# How do I call Here Maps app from JS in the browser?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am using JS in a browser and am trying to launch a new tab / call the installed Here Maps app. I'd like to pass in a destination and show the user directions.

I know in Google maps I can do this using the following:

```
var mURL = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=' + mAddress;
window.open(mURL)
```

and it either launches in google maps (if installed) or in a new tab if the native app is not installed.

Is it there something similar for Here Maps?

I found https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/routing.html but this is for displaying the map on my site, **NOT** what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is our DeepLinking API that allows you to share locations/routes via HERE applications (WeGo App, etc):

https://developer.here.com/documentation/deeplink-web/topics/share-route.html

For example: `https://share.here.com/r/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE` in your browser will open the HERE WeGo App showing a route between the first and second geocordinates. Also you can specify the mode of travel for the route, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. I didn't see an option on the link you provided but is it possible to pass in an actual address instead of a lat, long? Not a 'Share Id' but an actual address? i.e. https://share.here.com/r/mylocation/myaddress+city+state